# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: django, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to push my Django project to GitLab and build a build with the pipeline. But I get this error message every time: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

```
Code

stages:
  - build

variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/commits:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

build-docker-image:
  stage: build
tags:
  - docker
image: docker:19.03.12
services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind
before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD 
$CI_REGISTRY
script:
  - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
  - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
only:
  - main
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: There seem to be numerous related posts in the gitlab-runner issues forum, e.g., https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27300